# Does it matter what content-type I return with my FileContentResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, download, mime-types, content-type

I need to return a [FileContentResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filecontentresult?view=aspnetcore-2.1) in my action method which could be many things. A pdf, an image, an excel spreadsheet, etc...

How would I determine what content-type to return and what on the client(browser) is going to inspect/use that content/MIME type? If nothing besides javascript, how significant is getting the MIME/content type correct.

MIME and content-type are the same thing, right?

```
public IActionResult Download(string documentName,string filename){

string filePath = path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"Uploads",$"{documentName}_{fileName}")
byte[] fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
return File(fileContents,"What goes here?");
```

Comment: Look into `MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping` method

Comment: Yes it matters, because the browser uses it to select the correct program to open that file in with the content type

Comment: Remember that there are lot's of e.g. *dialects* of XML. if you deliver it as `application/xml` the browser should do one thing. If you deliver it as `application/xhtml+xml` (for example) the browser will do something else. It is possible for two sequences of bytes to have multiple interpretations, so if you know better what it actually is, definitely supply it. If you don't know better, `application/octet-stream` will usually trigger some browser heuristics where it's try to guess instead.

Comment: @Shyju MimeMapping class is not available in .net core, fyi

Comment: It is basically a dictionary where they store the mapping between extension and type names. You can copy paste that code to your .net core class and use it

Comment: @Shyju I discovered FileExtensionContentTypeProvider